# Switch players in a Java game

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple game for learing purposes. This game has two players, each it's own object. Every turn the players switch.

For every time it is another players turn I switch players using:

```
if (currentPlayer == playerOne)
{
    currentPlayer = playerTwo;
}
else if (currentPlayer == playerTwo)
{
    currentPlayer = playerOne;
}
```

Note that `currentPlayer` and `playerOne/Two` are objects of the same class.

I was wondering if it is bad to do it this way or if there are better ways to switch a player

Comment: What the problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible ? What's there to wonder ?

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question) Assume that it **is** possible, try something, and ask about what you tried if you get stuck.

Comment: @EJoshuaS When I see "is it possible" odds are it's a very new programmer.  It takes time to learn that nearly everything you'll attempt is possible, until you attempt something that's truly impossible. :)

Comment: @EdwinBuck Usually, "Is it possible?" means "how do I do it?", which just means "gimme teh codez."

Comment: Sorry, i worded my question poorly. I meant if it is bad to do it this way.

Comment: @Stixs It is not bad to do it this way unless you find that your other code is difficult to implement with this approach.  If you see that the other code is difficult to implement, then what is required to make the other code easier to write, think about, and maintain is what you should change your approach to.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do it that way.  All of your code would then deference the `currentPlayer` to figure out which player was the current one.

To do this both players should share the same type, perhaps a `Player` class.  You'd declare the current player as:

```
Player currentPlayer;
```

and construct your players

```
Player playerOne = new Player(...);
Player playerTwo = new Player(...);
```

Note that the `...` part is not what you'll be typing in, but a placeholder for the actual information you'll write when you design the `Player` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could hold the players in a list and switch them by getting their index in that list:

```
 // initialize
 List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(new Player(...),new Player(...));
 Player currentPlayer = players.get(0);


 // switch Player:
 currentPlayer = players.get(1-players.indexOf(currentPlayer));

 // version for more than two players:
 // select the next player from list and restart with the first after the last:
 currentPlayer = players.get((players.indexOf(currentPlayer)+1)%players.size());

 // similar by cycling the list
 currentPlayer = players.remove(0); // get the next player from list
 players.add(currentPlayer); // put it at the end of the list
```